# How do I take a blurry picture (like from an iPad 2) and sharpen it using iOS API's?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing, barcode

I have a picture of a barcode from the iPad 2 (or iPod touch 4G). I need to enhance the picture using sharpening techniques and other image enhancements so I can run the picture through a barcode scanner (like ZBar).

How can I do this with iOS API's? I'm a bit lost as to where I begin. I just want to take an image directly from the camera overlay and run it through a filter of some type.

Comment: With native CoreGraphics alone it'll be hard to manipulate the image without some serious code. It is possible though. There are numerous free graphics libraries that have sharpening algorithms.  Most are free some are paid. They are essentially wrappers, and entry points to CoreGraphics and do a lot of the leg work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Read a computer vision book and implement one of the advanced algorithms. iOS doesn't support it out of the box. And a simple sharpening filter isn't sufficient. You need more sophisticated algorithms.
2. Get a barcode scanner that supports these devices out of the box such as [Scandit](http://www.scandit.com).

The second option is the quicker one.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS5, you can use vImageRichardsonLucyDeConvolve_ARGB8888 contained in the vImage package. It implements the Richardson-Lucy deconvolution algorithm. I've personally used this on the Mac with great success - it all depends on how "blurry" your image is.

Comment: I don't recall - it was years ago - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look into Core Image and (especially) CIFilter. iOS 6 gives you CIUnsharpMask, for example.

Comment: On the iPad 2, the blur of the unfocused image is so strong and the width of the bars so narrow that the bars melt together and become indistinct. You cannot fix that with CIUnsharpMask.